# Ubuntu doesn't see other partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, mount

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS along Windows 10. My partitions set up is as follows:

[image]

Everything worked fine before and I could access my shared partition(`dev/nvme0n1p5`) perfectly fine, but with the latest restart all partitions other than home ceased to be visible:

[image]

Also, my swap partition is not used:

[image]
What exactly happened at the start up and how can I fix it?

Comment: No reason for 64GB of swap? Years ago when RAM was small you would have swap twice the size of RAM. But then it was recommended to have same, now 4GB swap partition is most often suggested. Only if hibernating, which is not recommended, may you need same as RAM or if editing videos, then you also may need larger swap.

Answer (score 1):

When dual-booting with any Windows 8 or newer users must disable the [Fast Startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) feature which is, in practical terms, hibernation. Once done shutdown Windows. Then boot Ubuntu as usual and the additional NTFS partitions should be again visible and mountable.

Regarding swap:

It shows `Swp [    0K/**2.00G**]`
2GB is the standard swap file size so this means that you're using the swap file and not a swap partition in this case. That's actually a good thing because you can now remove that absurdly huge swap partition and reuse the space.

Keep in mind that the more RAM you have the less is the need for swap.

Comment: Windows turns this back on with updates, so you often have to turn it off again.

Comment: Yes, true, you have to disable the hibernation!!!! Easy to do it persistently:Click Start, and then type cmd in the Start Search box.
    
In the search results list, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator!
    
When you are prompted by User Account Control, click Continue.
    
At the command prompt, type "powercfg.exe /hibernate off", and then press Enter.
    
Type exit, and then press Enter to close the Command Prompt window.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, Thank you for this answer. Actually, I need this amount of swap memory, as while training ML models I often come to/excess the limit of my memory and this amount of swap often saved me hours of processing. So my question is - do you have any idea how can I enable using the swap partition instead of swap file?

Comment: @jakes Certainly you don't need 64GB swap?!? That you may eventually need more than the default you're using now is conceivable but that much is inconceivable. Changing from swapfile to a partition is a matter of editing the fstab: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Answer (score 0):

If the solution of ChanganAuto does not work (=remove the windows "fast startup" option),
then another cause can be that you stopped Windows in **standby** (sleep) or **hibernate** mode. That also locks the windows partitions (under Linux, you cannot mount them automatically in RW mode with your session or update their contents).
=> If it is the case, then 2 steps :

- reboot Windows and shutdown it (in order to unlock the partitions)
- boot on Linux.

I hope it will solve your problem